# Dropdown login Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, navbar

I am working with mvc,c# and  boostrap. In my navbar I have a dropdown to login.It is placed like the facebook login, top right.

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><img class="img-responsive" src="/images/h-perfil.png" alt="imagen"> perfil <span class="caret"></span></a> <div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding: 15px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
        <form method="post" action="login" accept-charset="UTF-8">  
            <input style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="text" placeholder="Email" id="username" name="username">
            <input style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" id="password" name="password">
            <input class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" id="sign-in" value="Ingresar">
            <label style="text-align:center;margin-top:5px">Registrarme</label>
        </form>
    </div>
</li>
```

I was wondering how to use models to login the users. I have also a controller that uses my model. This is my controller

```
public ActionResult LogIn(UserModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) //Checks if input fields have the correct format
    {
        return View(model); //Returns the view with the input values so that the user doesn't have to retype again
    }
    if (credential valids) 
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", UserModel); }
```

So in this case  I would like users to login when clicking  the buton. Thanks

Comment: Can you post the UserModel class. Basically the properties of these class shouldmatch the name attribute of input tag. When you submit, UserModel class will automatically be populated

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer.  this

Comment: this is the model:                                    public class userlogin
    {    
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }                
So, you say that it will auto populate. But how can I call the controller action called Login, when clicking the button sign in? 
thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign correct value to action attribute.Use "Email" value for id and name for first textbox

```
<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("LogIn", "YourControllerName")" accept-charset="UTF-8">  
        <input style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="text" placeholder="Email" id="Email" name="Email">
        <input style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" id="password" name="password">
        <input class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" id="sign-in" value="Ingresar">
        <label style="text-align:center;margin-top:5px">Registrarme</label>
</form>
```

Decorate with HttpPost attribute:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogIn(UserModel model)
{
   //code
}
```